# Alter table to add Identity column based on Order By

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table

**Person**

```
------------------------------------
| **Id**  |**Name**  | **Created** | 
------------------------------------
| Guid1   | John Doe |  2016-01-01 |
------------------------------------
| Guid2   | Mary Jane|  2015-01-01 |
------------------------------------
```

Column Id is the PK and a Clustered Index, so I want to add an Identity Column:

```
ALTER TABLE [Person]
ADD
IdentityCol INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

The problem is that every time when I try to do this, it adds the value of IdentityCol, based on the default order of the table, which I suppose is defined by the column Id

**Person**

```
-------------------------------------------------
| **Id**  |**Name**  | **Created** | IdentityCol|
-------------------------------------------------
| Guid1   | John Doe |  2016-01-01 |    1       |
-------------------------------------------------
| Guid2   | Mary Jane|  2015-01-01 |    2       |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Buy what I want is that create the values order by Created column

```
-------------------------------------------------
| **Id**  |**Name**  | **Created** | IdentityCol|
-------------------------------------------------
| Guid1   | John Doe |  2016-01-01 |    2       |
-------------------------------------------------
| Guid2   | Mary Jane|  2015-01-01 |    1       |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Is there any way to specify the Order By in ALTER sentence?

Answer (score 5):

Use row number:

```
UPDATE Person p
SET IdentityCol = (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY Created) AS rn
                   FROM Person t WHERE p.Id = t.Id)
```

Then you could set the `IdentityCol` as a formal identity column via:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT database.schema.Person ON
```

Comment: Maybe use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT database.schema.Person ON`? and after the job is done set it to `OFF`.

Comment: is this valid TSQL?

Answer (score 5):

You have to create a new table with same structure + identity column. Insert the old data into it with ordering

```
Insert into ...
Select ...
Order by ...
```

Otherwise you have to think about adding a column (not identity) . Fill it with auto numbers in the order you want like @Tim answer. Then set it as identity

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is the correct way to solve my problem, but I ended with something like this:

First, I remove the index created by SQL for PK (Column Id).

```
ALTER TABLE [Person] DROP CONSTRAINT PK__PersonId
```

This works only if you don't have any table related to this by the column Id, and removes at the same time the PK of Person Table.

Second, I create a temporal clustered Index on Created column:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_CreatedTemp ON [Person] (Created ASC)
```

Now SQL sort the table based on the Created column, so now I can add my Identity column.

```
ALTER TABLE [Person]
    ADD IdentityCol INT UNIQUE IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

When the column is added, SQL automatically fills the value based on the default order, which is determined by the Index IX_CreatedTemp.

So the result is as I expected

** Person **

```
-------------------------------------------------
| **Id**  |**Name**  | **Created** | IdentityCol|
-------------------------------------------------
| Guid1   | John Doe |  2016-01-01 |    2       |
-------------------------------------------------
| Guid2   | Mary Jane|  2015-01-01 |    1       |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Now is time to return the column Id as the PK. First, I remove my temp Index:

```
DROP INDEX  IX_CreatedTemp ON [Person]
```

And now add the PK:

```
ALTER TABLE [Person] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id)
```

Finally, I added a new index based on my new IdentityCol to make my table faster

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_IdentityCol ON [Person] (IdentityCol ASC)
```

And everything is working fine.

Comment: Tables have no order. Implemenations have order, but selecting from a table is not guaranteed to refelect that order. So this only *seems* to work. Window functions let you select a new column holding a row_number per an order by as in  TimBiegeleisen's answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can not update IDENTITY cloumn,you delete and insert

```
select Id,Name,Created into #temptable from [Person]
TRUNCATE TABLE [Person]
ALTER TABLE [Person] ADD [IdentityCol] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL

INSERT INTO [Person](Id,Name,Created)
select Id,Name,Created from #temptable order by Created
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
update p
    set IdentityCol = IdentityColumn
from
    Person p
    join (select Id, row_number() over (order by Created) IdentityColumn from Person p2) SQ on p.Id = SQ.Id
```

Then turn on the identity:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT database.schema.Person ON
```