# How would I count rows for distinct groups, ordered by date?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Sorry if the title is a little confusing. A little background - We have customers who belong to certain groups, and those customer can change between groups at any time. I'm trying to create a column that chronologically list which groups the customers joined in what order, based on the date they joined said group.

This is what the table looks like:
Cust_Tbl

```
| Account | Group | Join_Date  |
|---------|-------|------------|
| 1000    | 21    | 2007-07-22 |
| 1000    | 26    | 2017-03-08 |
| 1002    | 21    | 2014-06-19 |
| 1002    | 23    | 2019-01-01 |
| 1003    | 26    | 2005-10-05 |
| 1004    | 21    | 2018-05-07 |
```

This is what I want it to look like:
Cust_Tbl2

```
| Account | Group | Join_Date  | Group_Order |
|---------|-------|------------|-------------|
| 1000    | 21    | 2007-07-22 | 1           |
| 1000    | 26    | 2017-03-08 | 2           |
| 1002    | 21    | 2014-06-19 | 1           |
| 1002    | 23    | 2019-01-01 | 2           |
| 1003    | 26    | 2005-10-05 | 1           |
| 1004    | 21    | 2018-05-07 | 1           |
```

As you can see, the groups are enumerated in chronological order, split by account.

I've tried plenty of other methods - including some code I found elsewhere on SO -

[Alter table to add Identity column based on Order By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795728/alter-table-to-add-identity-column-based-on-order-by)

I'm relatively new to this, so this wasn't entirely easy for me to understand (had issues with the identity property, but that isn't my main question)

The closest thing I've been able to come up with is a simple window function (which is also new to me). Obviously this doesn't work because it doesn't group by the account number.

```
select 
    *
    , ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Join_Date) as num 
from 
    Cust_Tbl
```

So far, I'm at a stand still. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Updated query to match tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your expected result, you just need to add [partition by account]:

```
select 
    *
    , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by account order by [group]) as num 
from 
    Cust_Tbl
```

You used [order by rate_str].

I do not know what the [rate_str] is. I think you can use order by [group]

**But:**

One thing you need to clarify is:

For example, I added the third row for account 1000:

```
| 1000    | 21    | 2007-07-22 |
| 1000    | 26    | 2017-03-08 |
| 1000    | 21    | 2017-02-08 |
```

Is your expected group order 1,2,3 or 1,2,2?

How about this?

```
| 1000    | 21    | 2007-07-22 |
| 1000    | 21    | 2017-03-08 |
| 1000    | 26    | 2017-02-08 |
```

Comment: Looks like this works so far! Awesome! Thank you! I've edited the original question (had some old code when I copy pasted). rate_str should be Join_Date. I've updated that to be correct. To answer your clarification question, the expected group order would read 1, 3, 2 for the second example. The first example wouldn't occur since there would be no *new* "Join Date" if they stayed in the same group. Essentially what we are tracking is IF the customers switch between groups, what day do they do it. So going from 21 to 21 wouldn't show up, since they're already in group 21. Thanks again!